# deformation retraction for a simple Hopf link

Tags: algebraic-topology

I would like to find a deformation retraction $F:X\times[0,1]\to X$ of the complement of the Hopf link which consists of two circles linked together once. Since Hatcher describes a deformation retraction in his book "Algebraic Topology" on [page 47](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), there should be a deformation retract of the $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus A\cup B$, with A and B linked circles described above, to the $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1\vee \mathbb{S}^2$.

Informal description: The deformation retraction for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with $|x|\ge1$ to the unit sphere is trivial to describe. But a deformation retraction deformation retracting $int(D^3)$ to $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1\vee \mathbb{S}^2$ is hard to find. I would push points near the first circle in the torus to the boundary of the torus, while points in $int(D^3)$ without the torus (around the first sphere) deformation retract to the $\mathbb{S^2}$ or the torus. I would be pleased, if someone could concretize the last description of the deformation retraction!

Is this rather informal description of the deformation reatraction correct? How would you describe the deformation retraction?

How can I formulate the deformation retraction $F:X\times[0,1]\to X$?

With kind regards,

Hopf_fibration

Comment: I can't tell if you're used to writing the term in another language or not, but in any case, in English "deformation retraction" is two words.

Comment: Sorry! English is not my first language. I will correct it.